# How can I automatically transfer an amount of Ether when I transfer my NFTs erc1155 to another account? That's my code

Tags: solidity, transactions, gas, nft, sendtransaction

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.4;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC1155/ERC1155.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Strings.sol";

//https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=19SSvs32m8I&t=648s&ab_channel=ArturChmaro

contract MyToken is ERC1155, Ownable {
    uint256 public constant Michelangelo = 0; //questi numeri finali sono gli ID non "amount";
    uint256 public constant Raffaello = 1;
    uint256 public constant Donatello = 2;
    uint256 public constant Splinter = 3;
    address public tokenOwner;
    uint256 gasRequired;
    address payable receiver;
    address payable owner;
    address payable _to;

    mapping(uint256 => string) private _uris;
    mapping(uint256 => uint256) private tokenIdToPayment;

    constructor()
        ERC1155(
            "ipfs/QmSAG4uLay8LxXNBgMTuLj42D65412cozk32KAmHeLNpD8/metadata.json"
        )
    {
        _mint(msg.sender, Michelangelo, 2, ""); //minta (con la funzione mint) "a chi te lo chiede" Michelangelo 2 volte, raffaello 4 volte etc.. ricorda che siamo nel constructor, quindi viene eseguita solo la prima volta;
        _mint(msg.sender, Raffaello, 4, "");
        _mint(msg.sender, Donatello, 3, "");
        _mint(msg.sender, Splinter, 1, "");
    }

    //Definisco la funzione di Mint
    function mint(uint256 tokenId, uint256 amount) public onlyOwner {
        //posso richiedere anche un address con "address account"

        if (tokenId == 0) {
            //mint NFT 1
            _mint(msg.sender, 0, amount, "");
        } else if (tokenId == 1) {
            //mint NFT 2
            _mint(msg.sender, 1, amount, "");
        } else if (tokenId == 2) {
            //mint NFT 2
            _mint(msg.sender, 2, amount, "");
        } else if (tokenId == 3) {
            //mint NFT 2
            _mint(msg.sender, 3, amount, "");
        }
    }

    //Definisco la funzione per l'uri
    function uri(uint256 tokenId) public view override returns (string memory) {
        return
            string(
                abi.encodePacked(
                    "ipfs/QmSAG4uLay8LxXNBgMTuLj42D65412cozk32KAmHeLNpD8/metadata.json"
                )
            );
    }

    //we have to specify the uri after to have mint the nfts.

    function setTokenUri(uint256 tokenId, string memory uri) public onlyOwner {
        //OnlyOwner in this way only "The Owner" can change the uri
        require(bytes(_uris[tokenId]).length == 0, "Cannot set uri twice"); //IN this way nobody can set twice, double time, the Uri
        _uris[tokenId] = uri;
    }

    function transferOO(address _to, uint256 _tokenId) public onlyOwner {
        require(tokenOwner == msg.sender, "Token not owned by sender");

        tokenOwner = _to;
    }

    function transferFAll(address _to, uint256 _tokenId) public {
        require(tokenOwner == msg.sender, "Token not owned by sender");
        tokenOwner = _to;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- Everything quite messes up. But with the question title the only thing I can think about is using [call](https://solidity-by-example.org/call/) inside your transfer function ( In this case is your mint() right? ).
- Just add : `_addr.call{value: msg.value}("");`
- And if the receiver is another contract, remember to add [receive()](https://solidity-by-example.org/sending-ether/) in receiver contract.